# Google Maps API: Is there a way to do proximity analysis to POI

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps API can I do proximity analysis, for example:

- In a state, let's say Virginia, display all the points that are 500 ft/m from a POI such as McDonalds or Bob's Diner, 1,000 ft/m from a National Park and within 5 minutes driving from an interstate highway (Example I-95)

Comment: I know that google earth pro allows this type of analysis; but I don't know if it uses gmaps api.

Comment: @relima - so my best bet is to create a POSTGIS db with all my POI and do the analysis on the postgis level but display the results on google maps

Comment: @dassauki that is exactly what I would do. You can use google's api to query distances to fill your db with more precise information or just go with pythagoras.

Comment: @relima - the issue with that is that i'll need to build a full blown postgis data, some form of tiling / wms server and my data sources won't be free and not as accurate as google's

Comment: I don't know the size of the db that you are dealing with; but in a small scale, I have used google docs spreadsheet application with a distances gadget or some sort of ditances function to create a table of distances that suits your needs; It won't help you at all if your db is anything but very small; but I am really out of other ideas.

Comment: @relima - would it be easier to use geoserver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Local Search within the Google Maps API (V3).

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/localsearch/places.html

sandbox:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=localsearch#markers_v3

You can even find POI's along a route if you wanted too:

http://gis5.com/pois_along_route/gm_pois_along_route.php