# Google Places Autocomplete Limit Suggestions to Local Area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but can I limit the suggestions that Google Places Autocomplete find to say 5 km of a certain location? If I'm in Dublin I don't want to see suggestions in Canada!

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/google-maps-api-is-there-a-way-to-do-proximity-analysis-to-poi

Comment: hmm, it seems viewport biasing would sort of do this. But why do Google insist on showing results if they are considered "more relevant" even when they're out of the area. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports

Comment: They (Google) are paid to show those - that's why google give the service/api away for free. That's why they make billions.

Comment: ah, that's ok then, so you're saying if I search for a residential address they're unlikely to have a paid result with similar search terms and nothing else should come up?

Comment: For UK/Ireland your get to Postcode/Area Name Level not individual addresses.

Comment: by "your get" did you mean you can only target your ad towards Postcode/Area Name Level?

Comment: Google have not purchased address point data from Ordnance Survey or Ireland Ordnance Survey, Only Postcode Sectors.

Comment: intriguing.. I want to use autocomplete for residential addresses throughout Ireland, are you saying Google doesn't have them? The few ones I've tried seem to match up.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the country that you searching in it in the google request. Just add to your url request the parameter:

```
 &components=country:kw
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `location=lat,lon` parameter, but can't find it in the documentation anymore. There is a `locationbias` parameter, though.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search